# HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required intermittent

Tags: python, security, ubuntu, firewall

This is more of a linux/security related question (than Python's urllib2 authentication question)

My setup is:

1. I am running a Ubuntu Server in my company's corporate network
2. I notice that when I try to access the internet via a browser (chrome or firefox), I intermittently get redirected to company's security page asking me for my company's credentials.
3. Ubuntu server's firewall is disabled.
4. I am not sure why, but when I try running the following script (to fetch data from internet, even google.com), this script intermittently fails due to `401 Authorization Required Error`. Once this happens, then I have to open a browser (obviously access via VNC) and then go to any page and I have to enter my credentials. And once I do, then the script runs just fine for a while. And after a while, it fails due 401 error again.

Script

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?countrycodes=us&state=colorado&street=6900+W+25th+Ave&format=json&addressdetails=1&polygon_geojson=1'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
print response

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amit/workspace/clink/device_polling/mydb/dbmanager.py", line 1554, in _poll_device
    self.update__device_geoloc(deviced_alldb, mydbc, hpnac, logobj)
  File "/home/amit/workspace/clink/device_polling/mydb/dbmanager.py", line 1387, in update__device_geoloc
    geoinfo = get_coordinates_geolocation(state=state, city=city, street=street, countrycodes=countrycodes)
  File "/home/amit/workspace/clink/device_polling/utils/utils.py", line 386, in get_coordinates_geolocation
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 629, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/miniconda/envs/py_env_clink/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
```

I don't understand why this is happening? Does any security guy know what I should look here for? I am sure it has to do with my corporate firewall which periodically requests my ubuntu server for password

Comment: Looks like the network guys in your company have configured an proxy server to the internet which requires authentication. Ask them if there is a way to whitelist your servers ip/mac there so that you can access the internet without authentication.

Comment: Great... thanks. Isn't there anyway I can do something from the server myself so that I don't have to deal with the politics of IT?

Comment: You could use http://www.seleniumhq.org/ to automatically enter the password in the webbrowser.  But that would be a pain in the ass to maintain because you would have to adapt the script whenever IT change something with the loging page. Further more would that be a very big security hole as you have to store your credentials somewhere on the server.

Comment: ya, totally understand... so the IT finally decided to give me the .crt file. not sure how to add it to my server... need to do some research on that now. thanks